# Why does this code with fork() only produce one output?

Tags: c, fork, parent, wait, child-process

Why does this code fragment only produce the letters "XUVUV"? I would think "UXUVV" would also be a possibility, but I never get that output.

```
if (fork() == 0){
    printf("X");
}

printf("U");
wait(NULL);
printf("V");
```

Comment: Could be buffering.  Try appending a newline to all of your `printf`s which will flush the buffer on most line-oriented terminal systems, e.g. `printf("X\n");`  Alternatively write to `stderr` which is (usually) unbuffered, e.g. `fprintf(stderr, "X");`

Comment: Can you explain how you think `UXUVV` would occur?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would guarantee one or the other output. So your expectation is unfounded. It is timing/scheduler dependent. And on your system, the timing/scheduler behaviour tends to produce one result over the other. But on another system or even on another day the result may be different.

Comment: Hint: the time quantum that the parent (or child) process is allowed to run is significantly longer than the time it takes to call three `printf()`s. Hence, your result is going to depend primarily on whether the child or parent process gets scheduled first after `fork()` returns. IIRC, in Linux the child almost always gets scheduled first, but that may not be guaranteed...

Answer (score 4):

There are no newlines printed; therefore, no output appears until the process terminates.

The child process adds `X` to its buffer; the parent does not print an `X`.  The child then adds `U` to its buffer.  It waits, but the wait returns immediately; the child has no children to wait for.  It adds `V` to its buffer.  It terminates, so the `XUV` is flushed.

Meanwhile, the parent has added `U` to its buffer; it then waits for the child to finish.  When the child has finished, the `XUV` has been printed.  The parent adds `V` to its buffer and exits; its `UV` are flushed to the output.

The consequence is that you see `XUVUV` every time.

You can't tell whether the child adds its characters to its buffer before or after the parent adds its `U` to its buffer, but you do know the child has completed before the parent adds the `V`, so the output is determinate unless you do something fancy like `setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0)` to make the standard output unbuffered before you do any output operations.

If you add newlines to each print operation, things get more complicated; the timing ceases to be determinate.